Why is my multiple SATA controller Linux system experiencing a lot of link resets and drives falling off?
I have a system running Fedora 41 (and dual-boot to my old Fedora 33) experiencing a lot of issues with disks dropping off the system.
The system is an AMD X370 series chipset with two add-on eSATA controller cards plus the onboard controller:
$ lspci | grep SATA
01:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] X370 Series Chipset SATA Controller (rev 02)
04:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1061/ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
08:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9215 PCIe 2.0 x1 4-port SATA 6 Gb/s Controller (rev 11)
0a:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1061/ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
0f:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)

It has a fair number of disks attached - 12 internal, plus 7 external.  Two of the externals are in multi-disk chassis using SATA expanders; the externals are not using the chassis RAID but JBOD funtionality.
Sample errors:
Dec 27 09:48:54 fedora kernel: ata11.13: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
Dec 27 09:48:54 fedora kernel: ata11.14: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
Dec 27 09:48:54 fedora kernel: ata11.00: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x200000 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Dec 27 09:48:54 fedora kernel: ata11.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Dec 27 09:48:54 fedora kernel: ata11.00: cmd 61/08:a8:48:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 21 ncq dma 4096 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x100 (unknown error)
Dec 27 09:48:54 fedora kernel: ata11.00: status: { DRDY }
Dec 27 09:48:54 fedora kernel: ata11.01: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Dec 27 09:48:54 fedora kernel: ata11.01: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
Dec 27 09:48:54 fedora kernel: ata11.01: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 20#012         res 40/00:90:08:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x100 (unknown error)
Dec 27 09:48:54 fedora kernel: ata11.01: status: { DRDY }
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.15: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.04: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.15: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.04: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.05: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.06: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.07: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.05: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.08: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.09: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.10: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.11: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.12: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.06: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.13: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.14: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 pangea kernel: ata11.00: hard resetting link
Dec 27 09:48:56 pangea kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is disabled
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.07: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.08: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.09: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.10: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.11: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.12: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.13: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.14: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Dec 27 09:48:55 fedora kernel: ata11.00: hard resetting link
Dec 27 09:48:56 fedora kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is disabled
Dec 27 09:48:56 fedora kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is enabled
Dec 27 09:48:56 pangea kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is enabled
Dec 27 09:48:56 fedora kernel: ata11.00: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Dec 27 09:48:56 pangea kernel: ata11.00: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Dec 27 09:48:56 pangea kernel: ata11.01: hard resetting link
Dec 27 09:48:56 pangea kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is disabled
Dec 27 09:48:56 fedora kernel: ata11.01: hard resetting link
Dec 27 09:48:56 fedora kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is disabled
Dec 27 09:48:56 fedora kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is enabled
Dec 27 09:48:56 pangea kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is enabled
Dec 27 09:48:56 pangea kernel: ata11.01: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Dec 27 09:48:57 pangea kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is disabled
Dec 27 09:48:56 fedora kernel: ata11.01: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Dec 27 09:48:57 fedora kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is disabled
Dec 27 09:48:57 fedora kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is enabled
Dec 27 09:48:57 pangea kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is enabled
Dec 27 09:48:57 pangea kernel: ata11.02: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Dec 27 09:48:57 pangea kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is disabled
Dec 27 09:48:57 fedora kernel: ata11.02: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Dec 27 09:48:57 fedora kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is disabled
Dec 27 09:48:57 fedora kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is enabled
Dec 27 09:48:57 pangea kernel: ahci 0000:08:00.0: FBS is enabled
Dec 27 09:48:57 fedora kernel: ata11.03: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Dec 27 09:48:57 pangea kernel: ata11.03: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Dec 27 09:48:57 fedora kernel: ata11.04: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
Dec 27 09:48:57 pangea kernel: ata11.04: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
Dec 27 09:48:58 pangea kernel: ata11.05: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
Dec 27 09:48:58 fedora kernel: ata11.05: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)

I can't think of an event that was a major change when this began.  One SSD failed, so I bought a new pair (everything is mdadm RAID1) and installed but one of the new ones kept dropping off the bus (power LED shows it powered off).  As these were in hot-plug trays I could unplug/re-insert the disk and it would resume working... sometimes I had to re-add to the array, sometimes not.  smartctl showed no errors.
I thereafter at some point added a new PCIe card (LSI HBA) and another 4-drive chassis for more capacity.  This seemed to make things worse.
The link dropping was not following the same disk.  Sometimes one of the internals (in the hotplug tray), sometimes one of the externals (also in a hotplug, in a chassis via eSATA expander).  Sometimes both disks in the mirror would just 'go away'.  I believe I've never seen a failure happen on one of the drives connected to an internal SATA controller however; FYI some of the 'internal' disks are connected to a port on one of the PCIe expansion cards.
I was recently rsyncing to disk in the external chassis (4-drive unit) and I could see the power/link lights all turn off, then turn on one by one, resume activity, then turn all off again.  That is the error log I posted above.
It's become quite unstable in that I'm multiple times a day re-plugging and/or re-adding a disk to the md array.
Are there known issues with multiple add-on cards?
I'm a bit stuck on troubleshooting this.  The behavior existed on Fedora 33 and I was hoping that something in Fedora 41 might have resolved it as 33 is well out of support, but alas...

Can you try and rule out physical interface issues? This answer mentions that links dropping and failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED errors were due to what was found to be a hot-swap SATA disk backplane.

By a quick glance I see what might be drives 0 to 14 being attached.
I'd suspect POWER being an issue (i.e. need special attention!) with that amount of drives, so I'd suggest:

SUM up of all the Ampere numbers - voltage grouped - for all the drives.
Now; Does the PSU (Power feed) have the capacity to provide that amount of power - at all times?
Note that startup power requirements might also be a special case.
Note also; running at the very limit may be problematic.
Yet another thing; heat (things running hot) is likely to have negative effects.
Further; software / driver issues, (IRQ?) latency, timing and related requirements may also come in.

